# How to setup the NCV7708B h-bridge/double hex driver?

Tags: spi, driver, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

I am working on a circuit to control an electromechanical display and settled on the NCV7708B Double Hex Driver ([datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCV7708B-D.PDF)).

I created a minimal setup on breadboard in order to test the chip:
[image: schematic]

I connected a load *R1* (just a resistor) in a H-Bridge configuration similar to the following diagram (Figure 5 from the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCV7708B-D.PDF)) and I expect it to dissipate 1W if OUTH3 and OUTL2 are enabled (or OUTH2 and OUTL3).

[image: h-bridge configuration]

The NCV7708B uses SPI with the following frame format (Figure 3 from the [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCV7708B-D.PDF)):

[image: frame format]

And here is what I sent to to the driver as captured by a logic analyzer (MISO is connected to SO):

[image: PulseView]

However, no current is drawn from the +10V power rail and nothing happens. Do you have any idea of what might be causing this issue? Did I misunderstand the datasheet on how to configure the driver? I double-checked the connections and tested this configuration with two different brand-new NCV7708B in case of a defect.

Comment: Ell to be honest base on your logic analyzer captured I do not see any error. Did you try to lower the SPI frequency? What logic analyzer you are using?

Comment: @G36 I tried both 1 MHz and 100 kHz (PulseView screenshot is captured @ 100 kHz). According to the datasheet, the device can clock up to 5 MHz @ 5V and 2 MHz @ 3.3V. I use a cheap [Saleae Logic clone](https://sigrok.org/wiki/VKTECH_saleae_clone). Do you have a previous experience with the NCV7708?

Comment: No, I don't have practical experience with NCV7708. But have you tried to set 1 to SRR? Sending 0x96 instead 0x12?

Comment: Yes, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I see from your capture that MISO is always low - what happens if you send the same command twice? MISO should tell you the drivers that are on. I would also suggest to add a decoupling cap to the 3V3, it is possible that the chip is resetting for some reason.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Thanks for the suggestion, I added a 10 µF decoupling cap to 3.3V (it didn't change the behaviour of the NCV7708). If I send the same command twice (as two 16-bit SPI frames), MISO stays low. Even if I wait 100 ms before sending the second command.

Comment: If I send one 32-bit 0x12000000 frame, MISO is 0x00009200. I believe this is correct behaviour for daisy chaining and that the SRR bit is set to 1 for subsequent drivers.

Comment: If you are getting back 0x9200 it means that the thermal warning is set. While this does not imply a thermal shutdown, it cerainly is a clue. With a 100 Ohm resistor you should be getting around 10 mA of current, well within the capabilities of the part. I have also seen there is under load detection, with trip currents right around your 10 mA. Can you reduce the 100 Ohm to 50 Ohm or so, and se if you still have issues?

Comment: I will try other resistor values. Isn't it 100 mA? I think that multiples of 16-bit words frames are for daisy chaining. Before reducing the setup to the minimal one described above, I started with daisy chained NCV7708 chips. _Daisy chain communication between SPI compatible IC’s is possible by connection of the serial output pin (SO) to the input of the sequential IC (SI)._ The exact behaviour is not described, and from my experiments it is as follows. SO outputs the latest 16-bit word with SRR set to 1 after the first frame so that the chips uses the latest received 16-bit word as input.

Comment: I tried with various resistor values without success. I think the next logical step is to check the timing in details using an oscilloscope. I will also try the NCV7708F variant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue came from the CSB setup time.

The datasheet specifies that (5) from the timing diagram below (Figure 2 from the datasheet) should be at least 100 ns. It is clear from the logic analyzer capture that there was no setup time.

[image: timing diagram]

Using the ESP32 platform with ESP-IDF, this can be adjusted using `cs_ena_pretrans`.